# Does Java listFiles().length return only files number or files+folders number

Tags: java, file, directory

I have a simple question: Does Java `listFiles().length` will return only files number or files+folders numbers of the folder on which it is called? It isn't explicitly stated in Java documentation and I need to know this.

Comment: It'd be trivial to test this on your own.

Comment: Don't use `File` in 2015!

Comment: @fge What do you recommend me to use instead?

Comment: `Files.newDirectoryStream()`, and with Java 8, `Files.list()` too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It returns both files and directories. You can check if it's a directory or a file with `isFile` or `isDirectory` method.

Answer (score 1):

That´s written in the documentation of the listFiles method

> Returns an array of abstract pathnames denoting the files in the directory denoted by this abstract pathname.
>
> If this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, then this method returns null. Otherwise an array of File objects is returned, one for each file or directory in the directory. Pathnames denoting the directory itself and the directory's parent directory are not included in the result.

Therefore it does return both